# User event ref count set to 2 after creation

Tags: opencl

If I check the reference count of my cl user event right after creation, I get a value of 2.  This seems like a bug to me: I was expecting a value of 1.

The creation call is:

```
cl_int errorCode;
cl_event evt = clCreateUserEvent(context, &errorCode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OpenCL object's reference count may also includes any internal references that the implementation holds to that object. As a developer, you have absolutely no guarantees about what the reference count for any object should be, at any time. The specification says:

> The reference count returned should be considered immediately stale. It is unsuitable for general use in applications.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I tell if the event has been properly released when my kernel is complete? i.e. how do I check for event resource leaks?